# .NET Core deployment to IIS error for the standard .NET Core web application

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to deploy a .NET Core 2.0 application to IIS. This is just the standard .NET Core web application that is created when starting a new project. The project builds and run just fine. However, when trying to publish to IIS via web deploy, I get the following error:

```
3/25/2018 3:45:08 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__88.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---

===================
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the error list?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur no errors at all. The project runs fine the error comes with trying to deploy the project.

Comment: Is it an error in a view? Views are pre complied on publish.

Comment: @Tratcher it is just the standard .net web application template. There were not modifications made to it. This is just a deploy test. It builds and runs perfectly as it should since there were no changes to the default template.

Comment: For anyone interested the error was due to group policy Forwarding. The project files where from a unc path. dotnet can't publish files from a unc path. Moving the files locally fixed the issue.

Comment: @Dblock247could you please elaborate further? I'm getting this exact same error.

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos I am not sure if your having the same problem that I had but In my case I was trying to deploy directly to a UNC path on the server (UNC Paths: https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230]). The publish command does not work with UNC paths. Try using web deploy instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)